# How to check if a string input is contained in a vector of struct

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, vector

```
struct Article
{
int Id;
string name;
string desc;
double price;

Article(int s, string n, string o, double c)
 {
    Id = s;
    name = n;
    desc = o;
    price = c;
 }
};

vector <Article> vArticle;

void GiveName(vector <Article> vArticle);
int main()
{
vector <Article> vArticle;

Article a1(1, "Banana", "Fruit", 7.99);
Article a2(2, "Apple", "Fruit", 5);
Article a3(3, "Book", "Bible", 309.99);
Article a4(4, "Laptop", "Laptop Lenovo", 4989.99);
Article a5(5, "Banana",  "Fruit ", 5.99);

vArticle.push_back(a1);
vArticle.push_back(a2);
vArticle.push_back(a3);
vArticle.push_back(a4);
vArticle.push_back(a5);

GiveName(vArticle);
}
```

```
   void GiveName(vector <Article> vArticle)
    {
    vector <Article> vInput;
    cout << "List of articles: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vArticle.size(); i++)
    {

        cout << vArticle[i].Id << ",  " << vArticle[i].name << ",  " << vArticle[i].desc << ",  " << vArticle[i].price << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << "Enter an article name" << endl;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    for (int i = 0; i < vArticle.size(); i++)
      {
        if (vArticle[i].name == input)
        {
            cout << vArticle[i].Id << ",  " << vArticle[i].name << ",  " << vArticle[i].desc << ",  " << vArticle[i].price << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Article not found" << endl;
        }
      } }
```

My code shows "Article not found" for every member that's not equal to the input, because of using for loop.
What's the best way to make it show, for example, if i write "Banana", it shows just the elements that contain name Banana.
And if none of the elements contain it, show "Article not found"?

Comment: As an aside. Passing the vector by value in GiveName is forcing a deep copy. Better to pass as `vector<Article>&`. And you have three declarations of vArticle: one with global scope, one local to main and one local to GiveName …

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a boolean flag to mark if the name was found, then you make a if out of the loop to see if it was found, and if not, print the "Article not found" message.

Like:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < vArticle.size(); i++)
  {
    if (vArticle[i].name == input)
    {
        cout << vArticle[i].Id << ",  " << vArticle[i].name << ",  " << vArticle[i].desc << ",  " << vArticle[i].price << endl;
        found = true;
    }
  }
if(found == false) {
  cout << "Article not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah, i tried that first but i didn't move the second if out of the loop. Thanks man!